# Node Passport Facebook SDK successRedirect vs callbackURL

Tags: node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have specific questions regarding 
https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-facebook

When I use passport-facebook .
I do like this for configuration.

```
passport.use(new FacebookStrategy({
  clientID: config.facebook.facebook_app_id,
        clientSecret: config.facebook.facebook_secret_id,
        callbackURL: config.facebook.callback_url,
        passReqToCallback: true
    },
      function(req, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
     //code for success: Function A
    }
```

And then to authenticate

```
passport.authenticate('facebook', {
        successRedirect: 'http://app.mykomae.com/#/app/dashboard',
        failureRedirect: '/auth/unauthorized'
    }));
```

what is difference between successRedirect vs callbackURL?

And when the function handler 'Function A: above code' is calling?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`callbackURL` tells facebook on which external address could it call back your application after the user completes the authentication form, whereas `sucessRedirect` is the pair of `failureRedirect` are internal routes executed depending on the authentication outcome.

`passport.authenticate(...)` orchestrates the whole process. The "happy" flow is roughly the following:

1. `passport.authenticate(...)` detect that there is an unauthenticated user tries to access the given route, redirects it to facebook oauth;
2. if facebook auth was successfull your verify callback is called (this is your "Function A"), which should match the user by facebook userid in your internal user database and set things up accordingly (typically create a session for the user);
3. If everything goes well the user gets redirected to `successRedirect`, which is usually an internal route like `/profile`, from that point you could use user data you looked up at the previous step.

I hope that explains it.

Comment: thanks for the answer, the steps.  When is callbackURL using in above steps? Is it never used?

Comment: Np. `callbackURL` is a full URL facebook could call your app back. This is where you want to call `passport.authenticate(...)`. E.g. when `callbackURL` is `http://your.domain.example.com/callback`, you'd want to place `passport.authenticate(...)` in a route like this: `app.get('/callback', passport.authenticate(...), ...)`.

Comment: I have specified 'successRedirect' and callbackURL together. In case of success login, which url will be called back? if two urls are called together, what are the orders? thanks again

Comment: First, your `callbackUrl`, there you must call `passport.authenticate(...)` which checks the incoming callback request (tokens and such), then if everything checks out, it redirects you to your `successRedirect`.

Comment: That makes me understandable, let me follow that logic. thanks